# Are there surveys asking Israelis what should happen to Palestinians?

Tags: israel, public-opinion, palestine

I'm seeing some recent polls asking Israelis if they support Palestinian statehood.

- [Pew Research](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2023/09/26/israelis-have-grown-more-skeptical-of-a-two-state-solution/) asks: "Do you think a way can be found for Israel and an independent Palestinian state to coexist peacefully with each other, or not?" In 2023, 48% of Israeli Jews said this is not possible and 15% say "it depends".
- [The Israel Democracy Institute](https://en.idi.org.il/media/23124/war-in-gaza-11-_data_eng.pdf) asks more recently, "Do you support or oppose the idea that Israel should agree in principle to the establishment of an independent and demilitarized Palestinian state?" Among Israeli Jews, 63% are somewhat or strongly opposed.

It is clear that a significant share of Israeli Jews are at least skeptical of Palestinian statehood. But is there any data on what they do support? [Some on the far right talk openly about expelling Palestinians permanently](https://www.wsj.com/world/middle-east/israels-far-right-calls-for-palestinians-to-resettle-outside-gaza-6f1a720f), at least from Gaza. Have any surveys been done to gauge the support for that? Does the majority prefer the status quo to remain indefinitely instead? I understand that [the question of what alternatives even exist](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/what-alternatives-to-a-two-state-solution-have-members-of-the-israeli-right-prop) is complicated, but I am asking specifically if there is any survey data that gets any deeper into what Israeli Jews think about it.

Comment: FWTW, the most recent Netanyahu plan is "10 years of occupation and then will see"--in my summary. https://www.timesofisrael.com/netanyahu-plans-for-israel-to-stay-in-gaza-for-10-years/

Comment: The same Israel Democracy Institute does polls on Israeli support/oppose annexation of West Bank, you can look that up

Comment: I do not know what random polls say, but the possibility that Palestinians will have any kind of state on currently disputed territories was zeroed out by the Hamas attack. Despite vocal anti-Israel supporters there is nothing the whole world can do (except maybe taking the Palestinians elsewhere). Pragmatically, these people will stay where they are, and the status Quo with expanding Israel settlements will continue for decades. So it is either Jews are dead or Palestinians live miserably. Then go ask people if they want to commit suicide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH [this](https://www.jpost.com/israel-hamas-war/article-782190) is not a poll ran by one of the pollsters I heard of before, but anyhow...

> The poll, conducted by Direct Polls Ltd. for the Sovereignty Movement a day ahead of the conference [“Lessons from Gaza – an end to the idea of two states”], also asked: “Are you for or against voluntary transfer emigration of the residents of the Gaza Strip to other countries?” A clear majority – 76% – responded in favor; 16% were against, and 8% had no opinion.
>
> Surprisingly, center-left voters from the Yesh Atid and National Unity parties, headed by Opposition leader Yair Lapid and Minister Benny Gantz respectively, responded similarly regarding the issue.  Among the Yesh Atid voters, 61% were in favor of the emigration, 24% were against, and 15% had no opinion. Among those who voted for Gantz’s party, 71% were in favor, 18% were against, and 11% had no opinion.

So, encouragement of "voluntary migration" of Palestinians appears to have broad popular support in Israel.

(OTOH a quick search shows that Direct Polls was involved in a bit of [controversy](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/372581) before, with results substantially diverging from other pollsters on other topics, but that was explained [in article by one of the Directors of [Regavim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regavim_(NGO))] as being entirely due to question wording, so YMMV. As for what's the Sovereignty Movement; [this](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpos.2022.963682/full) might help.)

I'm even less knowledgeable about TV channel polls reliability, but a similar one was [reportedly done](https://twitter.com/EpshtainItay/status/1738650575921635706) by Channel 14 at the end of Dec 2023:

> Poll this evening on Israeli Ch. 14: "To what extent do you support encouraging voluntary migration of Gazans?" 68 percent responded "very supportive."
>
> [image]

Looking carefully at the small logo there in the right-hand corner, it appears the pollster doing that one on behalf of Channel 14 was also Direct Polls.

Other Israeli pollsters don't seem too interested in polling on this topic.

Comment: Related in the short run https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86466/18373

Comment: Utterly bizarre but very relevant, thanks!